# Android Studio: Inserting files into the Assets folder

Tags: android, class, directory, assets

I'm trying to copy and paste a whole bunch of files/folders into my Assets folder (that I created in the **Main** folder by selecting **New** > **Folder** > **Assets Folder**). But I get this error:

```
Cannot create class-file
```

The file in question is `GUIDemo.class` but there are others like it, too. Any suggestions how I can copy and paste the assets files into my project?

Answer (score 3):

`Android Studio` uses `Gradle-based` build system, you should

1. putting assets/ inside of the source sets (e.g., `src/main/assets/`)
2. or create a folder under `res`
3. Try right click your app -- New -- Folder-- Assets folder

[image]

4. Change `Android` tag to `Project`, right click `src` --- `make module app`

[image]

Comment: That's what I did. I placed it inside `src` > `main`. I don't want it sitting in `res` though

Comment: I've done that. See my original question, I described doing just that (maybe not well, sorry)

Comment: That's wired, cuz I can create it smoothly. Have you updated your Android studio to latest one (1.0.2 or 1.1 Preview 2)

Comment: I'm using version 1.0.1, but I'm not sure if that's the problem. I'm new to all this (i.e., app making, Android Studio) so I'm sure it's my fault but I just can't figure it out

Comment: I am really trying to help, see the method 4 to give it try